# Modify a portion of an XML with key/value structure

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I need to write a SQL Server query to change the values of the following example XML, each one should have a different new  value:

Example:

From

```
<Item>
      <key>RabbitMQConnection</key>
      <value Tr="PropertyBag">
        <Item>
          <key>Encoding</key>
          <value>65001</value>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <key>HostName</key>
          <value>TESTHOST</value>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <key>UserName</key>
          <value>USER</value>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <key>Password</key>
          <value>PASS</value>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <key>QueueName</key>
          <value>TESTQUEUE</value>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <key>VirtualHost</key>
          <value>TESTVHOST</value>
        </Item>
      </value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
```

to

```
<Item>
          <key>RabbitMQConnection</key>
          <value Tr="PropertyBag">
            <Item>
              <key>Encoding</key>
              <value>65001</value>
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <key>HostName</key>
              <value>TESTHOST22</value>
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <key>UserName</key>
              <value>USER222</value>
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <key>Password</key>
              <value>PASS22</value>
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <key>QueueName</key>
              <value>TESTQUEUE22</value>
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <key>VirtualHost</key>
              <value>TESTVHOST22</value>
            </Item>
          </value>
        </Item>
        <Item>
```

I'm really struggling with `xpath` language, can I  get some help please?

Many thanks!

Comment: Please show us what you tried.

Comment: The XML is not well-formed. Also, it is not clear where XML is located. Is it a variable, is it a column in a DB table.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following.

You can modify the rest of the XML elements one by one by using the same approach.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
N'<Item>
    <key>RabbitMQConnection</key>
    <value Tr="PropertyBag">
        <Item>
            <key>Encoding</key>
            <value>65001</value>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <key>HostName</key>
            <value>TESTHOST</value>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <key>UserName</key>
            <value>USER</value>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <key>Password</key>
            <value>PASS</value>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <key>QueueName</key>
            <value>TESTQUEUE</value>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <key>VirtualHost</key>
            <value>TESTVHOST</value>
        </Item>
    </value>
</Item>';

DECLARE @HostName NVARCHAR(30) = 'NewTESTHOST';

SET @xml.modify('replace value of (/Item/value/Item[key="HostName"]/value/text())[1]
   with (sql:variable("@HostName"))' );

-- test
SELECT @xml;
```